# jquery - add extra data inside select tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Using jQuery, how do I add some extra info into a form select tag?

In my searching I have seen jQuery's append and add and html tags but it looks they add the info below the item, not in the item?

I want to add...

```
eform="Australian State::1"
```

into the line...

```
<select id="state-au" name="state-au">
```

so it becomes...

```
<select id="state-au" name="state-au" eform="Australian State::1">
```

I am hoping to use this in a MODx Evolution email form to make the Australian State select box a required field with jQuery - that select box is dependent on the country select box: If Australia is selected, the Australian State select box is shown. I am doing that with the following code so the new code would be added into this...

```
$('#country').bind('change', function (e) {
    if( $('#country').val() == 'AU') {
        $('#stateAU').slideToggle('fast');
    }
    else {
        $('#stateAU').hide();
    }
}).trigger('change');
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use jQuery's `attr()` method to add(or update) attribute to element:

Add new attribute with:

```
$("#state-au").attr("eform","Australian State::1");
```

Remove attribute with:

```
$("#state-au").removeAttr("eform");
```

Solution:

```
$('#country').bind('change', function (e) {
    if( $('#country').val() == 'AU') {
        $("#state-au").attr("eform","Australian State::1");
        $('#stateAU').slideToggle('fast');
    }
    else {
        $("#state-au").removeAttr("eform");
        $('#stateAU').hide();
    }
}).trigger('change');
```

I would recommend use `.data()` if you want to bind data to a specific element. Check the following example.

**Set data use**: `$("#state-au").data("eform", "Australian State::1")`

**Get data use**: `$("#state-au").data("eform")`

**Remove data use**: `$("#state-au").removeData("eform")`

> ### .data()
>
> Store arbitrary data associated with the matched elements or return the value at the named data store for the first element in the set of matched elements.
>
> REF: https://api.jquery.com/data/
>
> The .data() method allows us to attach data of any type to DOM elements in a way that is safe from circular references and therefore from memory leaks.
>
> #### .removeData()
>
> The .removeData() method allows us to remove values that were previously set using .data(). When called with the name of a key, .removeData() deletes that particular value. When called with no arguments, .removeData() removes all values.
>
> REF: https://api.jquery.com/removeData/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#state-au").data("eform", "Australian State::1");
  console.log($("#state-au").data("eform"));
  $("#state-au").removeData("eform");
  console.log($("#state-au").data("eform"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="state-au" name="state-au"></select>
```

Comment: Why would you add the w3schools reference before your link to jQuery's own comprehensive documentation? (Or at all? They're not a very reputable site, even though quality is higher than it used to be.)

Comment: Thanks so much for your help Daniel H. That sounds like a great way to do it. Please excuse my ignorance / lack of javascript experience but do I use that in the "country-bind-change" code inside the "if AU" bit? eg inside:
`if( $('#country').val() == 'AU') {`
And now that I think about it (so sorry), I think I might need a reversal scenario so that if Australia is unselected as the country, the eform="Australian State::1" code would be removed from the state select item (in the else section of the original jquery code) so that the hidden field is not required

Comment: @user3643520 OK check my updated answer with Example.

Comment: Thanks Daniel H! I appreciate the edit to make it easy for me to follow.
If I use the recommended data() method, do I use `$("#state-au").removeData("eform", "Australian State::1")` in the else statement? Do I also have to undo the console line in the else statement? I think it looks like it would work as expected but the MODX eform form doesn't seem to take the javascript on board. I may have to wrap your code into a snippet that the email form checks before submission. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: @user3643520 use `$("#state-au").removeData("eform");` check the updated code, it include a example of add and remove now

Comment: @user3643520 yes, remove the `console.log()` code those are just for debugging, also I have no knowledge about `MODx Evolution email form` so you might ask to another group, good luck!

Comment: Thanks @DanielH, really appreciate all the help. Excellent work. Thanks for confirming about removing the console.log. Cheers again

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#state-au").attr("eform", "Australian State::1");
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 supports data attribtutes which can be used to attach additional information/ data on DOM. Jquery supports this features using its data() method

```
<select id="state-au" name="state-au" data-eform="Australian State::1">
```

To get data we use

```
var eform = $("#state-au").data("eform");
```

To insert data we use

```
$("#state-au").data("eform", "Australian State::1");
```

Comment: Thanks for the post Sam. That sounds a nice way to do things. Unfortunately in this instance (because of the MODx eform snippet) I cannot change eform= to data-eform= as it cannot read data-eform=. Cheers